# DrawerLayout inside a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-constraintlayout, drawerlayout

DrawerLayout is not visible if I use **constraintLayout** as root layout it still opens and closes, but it's not visible. It works if I make **drawerLayout** as **root** or another layout like **RelativeLayout** or **LinearLayout**. Any idea why that is happening?

**This doesn't work**

```
<ConstraintLayout>
   <DrawerLayout>
```

**These works**

```
<DrawerLayout>
  <ConstraintLayout>

<LinearLayout>
  <DrawerLayout>

<RelativeLayout>
  <DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` acts as a **top-level container** for window content that allows for interactive **"drawer"** views to be pulled out from one or both vertical edges of the window.

That's why you can't make it as child to other `ViewGroups`.

Check reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout)

Comment: I don't think so, Google had been designed `DrawerLayout` to be used like this use-case. So, for your use-case, creating custom view will be last option to achieve such thing.

Comment: Allright makes sense so main layout always needs to be wrapped in drawerLayout, but if needed you can wrap drawerLayout inside another layout and that would work